# How can I display a <ul> as two side-by-side columns using CSS?

Tags: html, css, markup

How can I make 2 columns consisting of 3 rows ?

```
<ul>

<li>Item-1</li>
<li>Item-2</li>
<li>Item-3</li>

<li>Item-4</li>
<li>Item-5</li>
<li>Item-6</li>

</ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "flow to the right?" Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Check out the [holy grail on the subject](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks: I'm pretty sure OP means multi-column lists

Comment: I would like to create another column after item-3. I have limited vertical space in a footer would like to start moving items horizontally.

Comment: I don't get it... why not just [make it two lists and float left](http://jsfiddle.net/hEYHZ/)?

Comment: can you not just put it in a table? or make two list and float one?

Comment: That's the issue..I can't - the markup is generated through a CMS, creates a single list. Would be great if there was a way to constraint height so that additional elements would float to the right

Comment: Custom CMS developed by my company

Comment: Ask them to develop it _different_!

Comment: You could do it with a jQuery plugin: http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple pure CSS solution would be to have the List Items be 1/2 the width, and have them float left. This is an acceptable solution, so long as you can accept the following output.

```
Item 1         Item 2
Item 3         Item 4
Item 5         Item 6
```

The CSS would be:

```
ul.class-name li {
    float:left; width:50%;
}
```

There are some simple considerations:

- In IE pre 9, your container (`ul`) must have a width attributed.
- At 50%, you don't have any room for padding or border based on the way IE pre 9 calculates these vs. other browsers. (i.e. one incorporates padding into the specified width, the other adds padding to the width). Going down to somewhere between 47 and 49% often fixes those measly bugs.

Unfortunately, that is the only way the output can be if you are looking for pure CSS. If you need:

```
Item 1      Item 4
Item 2      Item 5
Item 3      Item 6
```

... then, Valchris' solution may be best for you.

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: I still prefer simple css solution rather than css3 solution or js.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a terrible-but-amusing CSS1 solution I put together years ago:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/two-column-list-pure-css.html

:)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

```
<ul>   
    <li> Test 1</li>
    <li> Test 1</li>
    <li> Test 1</li>
    <li> Test 1</li>  
</ul>
```

CSS is:

```
li:nth-child(n+3) {
    background-color:white; 
}
```

This should help

use this site: http://cssdesk.com/ to demo your code.